# Why people carrying the same SNP doesn't have the same Promethease report

Tags: dna-sequencing, genomics, health, snp

I'm a frequent user of Promethease to run health analysis based on MyHeritage SNP data dump.

I ran two people through Promethease and both have the same SNP:

`rs4307059 (T;T)`

In one report we see an Elevated Autism risk and in the other report we don't even see this SNP mentioned.

Does anyone ran into this same problem?

Comment: counterbalancing snips that reduce autism risk/lower some polygenic score?

Comment: Are the two VCF files from the same testing company and did they use the same version of the test?

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. Please take the [tour] and then go through the [help] pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site. In particular, this question seems like would be a better fit for [Bioinformatics.SE], but please do **not** [crosspost](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/), instead request migration. This site is intended for questions about biological process or mechanisms, but your question seems to be entirely about a software product and is thus off-topic for this site.

Comment: can you migrate it please?

Comment: I can't migrate as I am not a moderator — you can request migration of this question by flagging your post for moderator intervention and explaining what you want and why. ——— Also, if you want to notify a poster who isn't the original poster you need to @ them (e.g. @ppaulojr).